# What is this line of code trying to do?

Tags: perl

This Perl code is part of the variable declaration at the beginning of a piece of code. What does it mean?

```
my $EXPLICIT_YEAR = $ALL_PAGES ? 0 : ($store{year} || $current_year);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's equivalent to this:

```
my $EXPLICIT_YEAR;
if ($ALL_PAGES) {
    $EXPLICIT_YEAR = 0;
}
else {
    # $EXPLICIT_YEAR = $store{year} || $current_year;
    if ($store{year}) {
        $EXPLICIT_YEAR = $store{year};
    }
    else {
        $EXPLICIT_YEAR = $current_year;
    }
}
```

The `$conditional ? $true : $false` portion is a ternary if.
The `$store{year} || $current_year` portion uses the fact that the || operator returns the first value that evaluates to true, allowing $current_year to be used if $store{year} is "false" (zero, empty string, etc.)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if ($ALL_PAGES != 0)`?

Comment: Actually, I misread the when first writing.  It's a general scalar truthiness test, so your note is more correct than what I had, but not as correct as what I have now...

Comment: I would further add that this code (and pretty much any if-based solution that doesn't create a bunch of temporary variables) will evaluate parameters multiple times, while the ternary conditional will evaluate only once.  This would be important if `$store{year}$` were replaced with some function call that might be slow or might print to the console or might mutate global state.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $EXPLICIT_YEAR = $ALL_PAGES ? 0 : ($store{year} || $current_year);
```

This expression is using the [Ternary "?:" operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator), combined with a subexpression using the [`||` C-style logical OR](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Or). See [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

```
$ALL_PAGES ?
```

The expression before the `?`  - the condition - is evaluated as a boolean expression. A true value meaning any value that is not zero, the empty string or undefined (not declared).

```
0 : ( $store{year} || $current_year )
```

The values on either side of `:` are the values to be returned, depending on the return value of the condition. If the condition evaluates true, return the leftmost value, otherwise the rightmost. The leftmost value is simply zero `0`.

```
$store{year} || $current_year
```

The rightmost value is an expression itself, using the C-style logical OR operator. It will return the leftmost value, if it evaluates true (and ignore the rightmost). Otherwise it will return the rightmost value. So:

- if $ALL_PAGES is true, then set $EXPLICIT_YEAR to zero
- else if $ALL_PAGES is false, then:
- if $store{year} is true, then set $EXPLICIT_YEAR to $store{year}
- else set $EXPLICIT_YEAR to $current_year

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Perl developer, but I'm 99% sure (this holds in most other languages) that it equates to this: If the variable `$ALL_PAGES` is true (or 1), then 0 is evaluated, and if not, `($store{year} || $current_year)` is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I know 0 perl but a lot of C, so taking a guess here:

```
  Set variable EXPLICIT_YEAR to  
     (  if ALL_PAGES == true then 0  
        else ( (get store indexed at year) or current_year ))
```

The or operation is

```
false or false = false  
false or true  = true
true  or false = true  
true  or true  = true
```

Comment: I do believe that is the truth table for the AND operation.

Comment: Fixed the table as per @jb.'s comment.

Comment: That's not really the (Perl) "or" operation. It short-circuits and returns the last operand evaluated rather than some general true or false value. This is particularly relevant for this question.

Answer (score 0):

i think thats a way of doing a if/then/else
see here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_conditions.htm